# How to enable the Windows 10 "Containers" feature?

Tags: c#, powershell, win-universal-app, windows-10

Using the latest Windows 10 Fast Ring build 14316 (inside a VMware virtual machine), I'm trying to make the [Desktop App Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) function working.

When running the PowerShell script as advised:

```
PS C:\> .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Setup -BaseImage .\BaseImage-14316.wim
```

I'm getting an error:

> Assert-RequiredFeatureEnabled: fatal error 1000: required feature is not installed or enabled. Please refer to machine setup instructions.
>   In C:\MyPath\DesktopAppConverter\converter_util\EnvironmentAssertions.ps1:40 Zeichen:9

When looking into the mentioned source code, it seems that this line fails:

```
$feature = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Containers"
```

I've already tried to enable various Windows features without success.

**My question:**

What is this "Containers" feature and how to enable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quote from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter):

> Supported operating system
>
> Windows 10 Anniversary Update **Enterprise** edition preview (Build 10.0.14316.0 and later)

Comment: OMG, that seems to be the solution! I'm currently having Windows 10 Home only. Will try to update, thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure you select "Fast Ring" when you enable insider builds.  I did slow ring and I got Build 14295, which doesn't have it.

Comment: Actually, Containers show up in my Windows 10 Pro build 14332 as well

Comment: Appears to be available for Windows Professional too. PowerShell [command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10): `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers -All`

Answer (score 18):

Just run this command in PowerShell:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All`

Click Y. It will restart. After that, you're good.

I ran that command on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: This error warning came :
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: @IbadShaikh run powershell as admin, then execute that command

Answer (score 3):

Now, you need to enable "Get Insider Preview builds".

Here where it is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Hyper-V didn't get installed correctly either
Try to remove them, then install manually to see if that helps. Make sure you run power shell as an admin.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName microsoft-hyper-v -online
restart-computer
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
restart-computer
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 
$("VirtualMachinePlatform","Microsoft-Windos-Subsystem-Linux") 
restart-computer
```

Answer (score 0):

Check and start with clean image using DISM:

```
sfc /scannow (will take some time)
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```

If not working:

```
dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase (Should Work)
```

then Install Full Feature "Containers" with WSL (you can allso upgrade to WSL2)

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart

dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:VirtualMachinePlatform /norestart
```

and finally:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Containers /norestart
```

There is a list of DISM features to enable or disable:

```
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/enable-builtin-windows-features-through-dism/e4233e83-9068-474c-a40d-62a54ec7a136
```

Answer (score -3):

Containers are part of Hyper-V running in Windows Server only. I do not think that they exist for Windows 10 OS.

[See here for reference](https://charbelnemnom.com/2015/09/why-windows-server-containers-and-why-you-need-to-look-at-containers-hands-on/).

Comment: Thanks. How do I have to view this in the context that the Desktop App Converter is explicitely said to be used on Windows 10 build 14316? Maybe the "Containers" do mean something else here?

Comment: Actually, the most recent Windows 10 builds have Containers as well, you can enable them in Programs and Features->Windows Features, or through the usual dism or powershell methods