# Desktop App Converter Feature Containers Not Available

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

[image]I'm trying to convert my app to a Windows 10 Appx

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_1.0.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 : DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_FEATURE_NOT_AVAILABLE': Required Windows Feature 'Containers' is not available
on your system. Please refer to converter system requirements at https://aka.ms/converterdocs.
At line:1 char:1
+ &'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_1.0.1.0_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DesktopAppConverter.ps1

Do you know how to fix this?

I am using the CMD entry point. My OS is Windows 10 Home 14393

Comment: How do you process this conversion? are you using any third party tools?

Comment: No: Here is the command I entered DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer "C:\Users\Munni - Fam\Desktop\App.exe" -Destination "C:\Users\me\Desktop" -PackageName "MyApp" -Publisher "CN=<Red+Black>" -Version 0.0.0.1 -MakeAppx -Verbose

Comment: So you are using `DesktopAppConverter` from power shell right? and `App.exe` is your application

Comment: Is it possible to include the screen shot of the command window with the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable the Windows 10 "Containers" feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590514/how-to-enable-the-windows-10-containers-feature)

Comment: @Akinni, how so? Your error says you are missing "Windows 10 Containers" feature, the linked question is related to enabling "Windows 10 Containers" feature in the context of DesktopAppConverter. Please explain why your case is different?

Comment: @Akinni, yes I have, and so you've ruled out that you are running the correct edition of Windows (Pro or Enterprise) and which has the Windows 10 Containers feature and also running the correct windows build, which is a requirement regardless of whether you are doing base images or not?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Home Build 14393.447

Comment: As answered in the [question I marked as possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36597012/2641278), you must be running Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise to be able to use Windows Containers feature, a mandatory requirement for the Desktop App Converter. The web pages linked in your error message (https://aka.ms/converterdocs) also clearly states this as a requirement!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [How to add Containers to Windows 10](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-desktop-apps-universal-windows-platform-apps-desktop-bridge), we can do this.

1. Open **Control Panel**.
2. Click on **Programs**.
3. Click on **Turn Windows Features on or off**.
4. Check the **Containers** option.
5. Click **Ok**.
6. Click **Restart** to complete the task.

I also suggest you to use **Desktop App Converter tool** that enables you to bring your existing desktop apps written for .NET 4.6.1 or Win32 to the Universal Windows Platform(UWP).

**Please note** that some system requirements you should meet.

1. Windows 10 Anniversary Update(10.0.14393.0 and later) Pro or Enterprise edition.
2. 64 bit(x64) processor.
3. Hardware-assisted virtualization.
4. Second Level Address Translation(SLAT).
5. [Windows Software Development Kit(SDK) for Windows 10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).
6. Download the [DesktopAppConverter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/desktopappconverter/9nblggh4skzw)  and the [base image .wim file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54283) that matched your build.

More detailed information you could refer to [Desktop App Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter).

Comment: Great, my Control Panel does not have **Programs** option. And when I finally found the **Turn Windows Features on or off** dialog, there is no **Containers** option. Isn't this fun?

Comment: i don't have Containers in Turn Windows Features on or off
my windows 10,1709 build 16299
64 bit(x64) processor.

Answer (score -2):

ouch I was on the win 10 home laptop... wrong one.
I suppose to be on the win 10 pro at least